# Why is this list comprehension for appending digits from input not working?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Hi new to Python and trying to learn using comprehensions. 
Developed below code to read numbers in a string and extract the numbers however trying to replace with a single comprehension statement. Please advise

```
sent = input('Enter a string')
digit = []
for i in range(len(sent)):
    if sent[i].isdigit():
    d = sent[i]
    digit.append(d)
```

Tried below method

```
digit = [d for i in range(len(sent)) if sent[i].isdigit() = d]
```

Comment: Could you describe what the problem with the list comprehension you've come up with is?

Comment: @Josh: `d` is undefined in the OP's list comprehension, they seem to want the list-comprehension to both test if `sent[i]` is a digit, and assign it to d(?).

Comment: If the answer below helped, feel free to accept (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 1):

You are close; this is one way:

```
sent = input('Enter a string')
# 123

digit = [int(sent[i]) for i in range(len(sent)) if sent[i].isdigit()]

print(digit)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

A more Pythonic approach is to iterate values directly:

```
digit = [int(i) for i in sent if i.isdigit()]
```

The problem with your code is `d` is undefined in your list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the help